# How to utilize the Cygwin ack tool from Vim 7.4?

Tags: external-command, cygwin

I used Cygwin perl and cpan to download, compile and test a working `ack`, struggling with a clean working model.

Primarily using win32 Vim, it seems like I can only utilize the Cygwin `ack` if I change from `$COMSPEC` to `c:/cygwin/bin/bash.`
Unfortunately, this breaks other useful tools within Vim.  I have loaded the plugin [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) which seems promising, but it encounters an error after search execution and fails to render in quickfix. I have read many posts but haven't found a palatable implementation.

**What is the best mechanism for executing an external `ack` in Cygwin from win32 Vim?**

Perhaps I should look further at the Ack.vim implementation?  Maybe just something as simple as quickly switching between shell implementations without Vim restart?

Comment: I prefer to avoid installing a win32 perl implementation if that is fair to preclude as a potential solution.  While I would expect that path to work, seems that I should be able to avoid doing so, yes?

Comment: I recommend Ag or Ripgrep instead, as they work with Window's vim/gvim.  They are also much faster, and also works with ack.vim plugin.  For example, to use ag as search engine for ack.vim, in .vimrc, add line `let g:ackprg = 'ag --vimgrep'`.   Install ag or ripgrep on windows side, not on Cygwin side to make it work on both sides (win, cygwin)